# Would an (NH3)2+ molecule be trigonal planar like BH3 rather than trigonal pyramidal?

Tags: molecular-orbital-theory, molecular-structure, group-theory

I've been learning about using MO theory to explain why $\ce{BH3}$ and $\ce{NH3}$ have different geometries and by following the line of reasoning used to rationalise the differences in geometry I came to wonder whether ionisation or the addition of electrons to a molecule can change its geometry.

Eg: $\ce{NH3}$ is trigonal pyramidal but an $\ce{NH3^2+}$ ion would have the same electron configuration as $\ce{BH3}$, which is trigonal planar; does this mean $\ce{NH3^2+}$ would be trigonal planar?

Edit: My bad when I first posted this I wrote $\ce{NH3^2-}$ but meant $\ce{NH3^2+}$, this was just an example, my main objective was to find out whether changing the geometry through ionisation was possible.

Comment: The short answer is: yes. The slightly longer answer is: a molecule always reacts to a change within itself or the environment.

Comment: It would likely launch off proton and become H2N+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not only is changing shape due to ionization possible, it has been observed.  Not with ammonia as suggested in the question, but with [cyclooctatetraene](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclooctatetraene), which is nonplanar in its neutral state but [switches to a planar, aromatic ring structure when reduced to its di-anion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclooctatetraenide_anion).